# Obtaining facebook cover photos

Tags: android

How I can get the cover photo of the albums of a user in my application?
Currently, I have a json like this:

```
"id": "00000", 
  "albums": {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "428076573767", 
        "from": {
          "name": "Benjamin", 
          "id": "00000"
        }, 
        "name": "Profile Pictures", 
        "link": "https://www.facebook.com/album.php?fbid=00000&id=00000&aid=00000", 
        "cover_photo": "10151465301937683", 
        "privacy": "everyone", 
        "count": 57, 
        "type": "profile", 
        "created_time": "2010-09-05T08:42:19+0000", 
        "updated_time": "2013-04-27T23:53:11+0000", 
        "can_upload": false
      }, 
}
```

How I can get the cover_photo by URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get cover photo by adding this into URL. No need to extract cover_photo from Json .

```
album['id']?>/picture?access_token=12345

  // where album is JSON array and access_token is random here..
```

Try this. It will work.